# Why exist users with negative reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, users

Looking at the list of users, if one goes to the final page, one notices that there is people with negative reputation. Why they have negative reputation? Isn't "$1$" the minimum a user could have of reputation?

Comment: I guess you're looking at the ratings over the last week/month/quarter/year, not the all-time ratings. It's entirely possible to lose reputation during such a period (bounties are a method to lose large amounts of reputation that won't quickly be compensated unless one has high activity).

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice. Thanks! (Should I delete the question?)

Comment: Or retag as [meta-tag:support]. Somebody else might have the same confusion.

Comment: Reminds me of the story about the guy with such a negative personality that when he entered a room, people would look around and ask, "Who just left?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One cannot have negative total reputation, but one can of course lose reputation during a set time period. Bounties are a popular method for such reputation losses. In the reputation leagues for a fixed time period (the last week/month/quarter/year), the reputation change during that period is listed. In the all-time reputation league, the current total reputation is listed, and that is never below 1.